# Visual Studio 2005 Macros stop working when Visual Studio 2008 is installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, visual-studio-2005, macros

I have a number of macros written for Visual Studio 2005, but they have since stopped working once I installed Visual Studio 2008 on my computer. No error is returned by the macro when I try and run it, and the environment merely shows the hourglass for a second and then returns to the normal cursor. Currently uninstalling one or the other is not possible, and I am wondering if there is anyway to get the macros to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to install (reinstall) VS 2005 SP1, since a security update from Microsoft (KB928365) on July 10 may have caused the issue.